# Munin-Graph for "eth* traffic" gets into negative values

Tags: ubuntu, munin

I've installed an configured Munin on one node and munin-node on three nodes at digitalocean.

First I got the issue that eth0-traffic graph was enabled but not generated - for this I found this patch: https://github.com/mail-in-a-box/mailinabox/issues/896

I also set the speed to 1000 Mbit (which is shared by digitalocean hostsystem) because my servers also returned -1 at cat /sys/class/net/eth0/speed

Now I get graphs with different values but there are negative values which cant be right.

https://postimg.org/image/5mzppbx6j/
https://postimg.org/image/phlrbg4ob/ (eth0-errors is constant 1)

Answer (score 0):

The negative value is the number of bytes in as per the label on the left.  It is typical that the number of bytes in is significantly less than the number of bytes out.